# Post image missing when pasting link into Facebook despite the correct og:image meta tag

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-social-plugins

Within head tags of this post page (sorry there's a language selection prompt screen), Yoast SEO Plugin generates this:

```
<meta content="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/whatever.jpg" property="og:image">
```

Although the image linked here is Facebook compliant (above 200x200px), there's still no image appearing when pasting the post link into Facebook. My question is: why?

[Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) solves the problem on a post basis, which is unacceptable because my client would have to use it for every new post created (no image appears for all new posts shared on FB).

I can make it work to some degree using [this comment's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289336/664741):

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_og_og_image', function ( $content ) { return $content . '?scrape=true'; } );
```

But it only works after pasting an URL at least three separate times in FB with page refresh between each time, so still no acceptable.

Comment: Please, if my answer is ok , then approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add tags specifying the width and height of the image, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913458/871404

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive"/>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="www.domain.com/img.jpg"/>
<title>loading...</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">window.location="www.domain.com";   </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot see the image the first time the post is shared is explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching):

> When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will
>   scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to
>   see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that
>   the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered
>   image

The solution?

> 1. Pre-cache the image with the URL Debugger Run the URL through the URL debugger to pre-fetch metadata for the page. You should also do
>      this if you update the image for a piece of content.
> 2. Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it
>      immediately without having to asynchronously.