# Messenger bot pictures cached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using express static to host pictures that my bot uses in cards. As I updated the pictures, nothing changed.

With some inspection in a browser, it seems likely, that Facebook caches my pictures.

Here is the url that Facebook fetches:

> https://external-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBuS02rfKAdYlVs&url=my_url&_nc_hash=AQA-wiEHYNeC11mJ

This is the old version of the picture. Although if I go to `my_url` referenced above, I get the updated, correct picture.

How can I force Facebook to reload this resource in cache?

**UPDATE:**
I scraped my urls with [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing), it shows the correct pictures, but in Messenger I still see the old versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to get the scrape working with messenger as well. What does seem to work, though, is "busting" the cache with useless query parameters.  For example, if I want to show the image -

`http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png`

in messenger but I want to be able to modify the image, I just use

`http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png?cachebuster=0002`

When the value of cachebuster changes, Messenger will not find the cached item and will re-fetch your image.  You can name the query parameter whatever you want of course.  You could use a random number for the cachebuster value if you want to fetch every time, or you could just increment the value with each build or by hand when you modify an image.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's similar scenario
[How to clear Facebook's image cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285522/how-to-clear-facebooks-image-cache/10289336)

Your previous business card won't be changed, but its supposed to change on newly posted business card.

Comment: I tried this tool, but for whatever reason it didn't work. In the end I renamed my new pictures...