# how to clear facebook stream cache

Tags: facebook, caching

I am using facebook `publish_stream` method to post feed on facebook user timeline. The post is containing the image URL and title with some description. However the posted image could be change later but that change couldn't reflect on facebook side as they had cached the image.

So I wanted to be know how could clear the facebook cache on publish stream so they can show the latest image on user timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Once a image has been published on Facebook, FB will always show the cached version. if, however, you want to update the image for a new post, try running the URL to the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to update Facebook's cache. Any existing posts that use this image won't be updated.

It's to prevent people from changing content once it's already shared - otherwise it won't represent what the user originally shared. This would be something spammers could easily abuse.

Comment: but in publish_stream case in attachment image URL containing our server, so if later image could be updated then is it not possible to reflect this change on FB side too? as it contain our server URL. I think FB Debug Tool fine for updating sharer pages.

Comment: No, because Facebook will continue to use the cached URL (they make a copy if your image). If you inspect the source of a facebook page / stream post, you will see that your server's image isn't referenced directly.

Comment: I think if facebook using cache mechensim then it could be handle somehow....here is my another post - [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329105/how-to-clear-share-link-caching/12177868#12177868[/link]

Comment: Yes, but caching of the stream is controlled by Facebook. Clearing the cache will have no use here. Try it yourself. Share a photo on the stream, change the photo, clear the cache via debug took and see if it updates Facebook. You will find that clearing the cache has no effect. It's to prevent people from changing content once it's already shared - otherwise it won't represent what the user originally shared.

Comment: _“so if later image could be updated then is it not possible to reflect this change on FB side too?”_ – only for _new_ posts, but not for existing ones. Imagine I post a link to my wall, and the og:image points to _a lovely picture of a granny having a cup of tea_ – and then, some two weeks later, the site owner changes that (the image URL or the image itself) to the _picture of a shaved bunny in some sexual explicit situation_ … would _I_ want to have that change in image content to be automatically reflected on my wall, maybe without me even noticing? Of course not.