# Why does FB Like post wrong image to fb wall

Tags: facebook, image

When clicked on the fb like button on i.e. http://www.joanieart.com/collection.php?ix=15 I want to control the image posted to FB.

Im having a hard time getting this to work. Read tons of postings but no succes.

I tried `meta property="og:image"` and `meta rel="image_src"` but still it picks the wrong image.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think the metadata

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

is the right solution. If you have already tried this, try to force to refresh metadatas inserting page link here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It's the officially documentation

> You can update the attributes of your page by updating your page's tags. Note that og:title and og:type are only editable initially - after your page receives 50 likes the title becomes fixed, and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed. These properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked the page already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits are reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and type. For the changes to be reflected on Facebook, you must force your page to be scraped. The page is scraped when an admin for the page clicks the Like button or when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter. You can programmatically force your page to be scraped by cURL'ing the linter.

Comment: DeLac tx for reply. I cleared 2 warnings with the debug tool and there are no more errors. The debug tool picks the correct image but when i click the fb like on my website it still post the wrong image.

Comment: if the debug tool shows the corretc pic, it should be a cache problem somewhere in the net. Try to empty your own browser cache in the meanwhile

Comment: For sure it is cache!! I found an article on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329105/how-to-clear-share-link-caching/12177868#12177868 and ran the php code. After that the right pic shows. Clearing browser cache didnot work. DeLac tx for the tip